# Approach for Shortest Job First Scheduling

Tags: algorithm, sorting, scheduling, priority-queue

I have a list of jobs along with time required to complete the job. I need to come up with a way the jobs can be schedules using shortest job first.

**Approch 1:**
Dont preprocess.
Select the smallest job every time : O(N)

**Approch 2:**
Build a priority queue. Preprocessing time is : O(N)
Selecting the smallest job : O(logN)

**Approch 3:**
Sort the jobs. Preprocessing time is : O(NlogN)
Selecting the smallest job : O(1)

Having the time complexities, how can I come up with the correct approach.
If I assume my list of length N,then the total time would be.
**Approach 1:**  N * O(N)
**Approach 2:**  O(N) + N * O(logN)
**Approach 3:**  O(NlogN) + N * O(1)

In this type of scenarios, how to select the best approach. Broadly how to compare between mulitple ways that have pre-processing time?

Comment: Do new jobs arrive? If so, then using a priority queue (approach #2) would beat approach #3.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is clear that approach one has the worse complexity. Regarding your 2 and 3, it is not clear what to select. It depends on the constant in big-O and on the data that you process.

So I would recommend taking your own data and benchmarking with various sort algorithms on your data.